# 100% width layout not working properly in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css

1st sorry if the title is not 100% at the pont, i really have no idea how to compose it.

Anyway here is a simple problem with 100% width layout. I have a form that is inside a fluid container, it has - 1 input, 1 select, 1 button, they all are align inline (horizontal)

the problem when i minimize the window the button and then the select list they move down. which i dont want that.

Here is a example in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4GSLE/ you can minimize the html part and you will see the problem.

How to make them to be in one line and not to move down?

```
.main {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
form {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    display: block;
}
.clear {clear: both;}
input, select {
    float: left;
    height: 50px !important;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 66% !important;
    border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
    margin-right:  20px;
}
input.button {
    height: 54px !important;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: -1px !important;
    width: 125px !important;
    border: 1px solid #d6d8db !important;
    background: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
select {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 52px !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="main">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="" value="search" />
        <select>
            <option>select</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Search now" class="button" />
    </form>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CSS tweaking to the form, input, and select selectors should do the trick.

```
form {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
input, select {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 66%;
    border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
    margin-right:  20px;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4GSLE/2/)</kbd>

Side note: Unless you really need them, all those `!important` declarations will end up causing more trouble than solving issues. I'd avoid `!important` as much as possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but can you see in your DEMO when minimizing it gets out from the main DIV. Normaly it should stay in the container!

Comment: @AndrewS That's a different matter and primarily due to your mixing measurements. You've got some elements with a % width, and others with a hard coded width. If you want the entire thing to be dynamic, and you want to use hard coded widths, you'll need to adjust.... Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4GSLE/5/

Comment: main div is MAX-WIDTH, that means that on my monitor it can be maximum but on yours if resolution is less then 1200px width, will be smaller. So, from now i gues you understand that the INPUT which is has width in % this must be like ruber/silicon/flexible :) when window gets smaller, and 2nd the SELECT and BUTTOn must be inline, only the input[text] must get smaller.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4GSLE/7/ if you use % for the widths and adjust the form CSS, all is fine. You don't really even need the `.main` div.

Comment: well, i thought of looking for a solution like if select and button has fized width in px and the input in %. its part from the design

Comment: The fixed widths are the issue. They break the fluid design since 55% (text input) + 200px + 125px is often wider than the window. You can try setting a min-width for `.main` or  min-widths for the select and button.

Comment: A round-about method with fixed widths may be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4GSLE/8/ but that's sort of "hackish"